# Angular JS Comment / Reply Query

Tags: html, angularjs

[Picture Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gamJr.jpg)

Hi guys!Having this issue with Angular JS,which is bugging me for a while now,so decided to get some help,have in mind I'm new to Angular,so be gentle:).I want to make a simple Angular JS Comment / Reply section.I did it and it's working,but not the way I want it to.I want the reply section to post the replies above its container,not below it.I want when posting a reply for it to appear above the reply text area,but below the comment that has been posted.How can this be done,your help will be very much appreciated?Here's the code I wrote:

HTML:

```
            <div id='dv1'>
            <form ng-controller="FrmController">
                <form ng-controller="FrmController">
                    <textarea ng-model="txtcomment" placeholder="Comment..." style='width:510px'></textarea>
                    <button ng-click='btn_add();' id="commentBtn" style='margin-top:5px;'>Post Comment</button>
                    <ul>
                        <textarea ng-repeat="comnt in comment" style='width:510px'> Comment: {{ comnt }} </textarea>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id='dv2'>
            <form ng-controller="FrmController2">
                <form ng-controller="FrmController2">
                    <textarea ng-model="txtcomment2" placeholder="Reply..." style='width:510px'></textarea>
                    <button ng-click='btn_add();' id="replyBtn" style='margin-top:5px;'>Reply</button>
                    <ul>
                        <textarea ng-repeat="comnt in comment" style='width:510px'> Reply: {{ comnt }} </textarea>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And the JS function for the comment section:

```
function FrmController($scope) {
$scope.comment = [];
$scope.btn_add = function () {
    if ($scope.txtcomment != '') {
        $scope.comment.push($scope.txtcomment);
        $scope.txtcomment = "";
    }
}
$scope.remItem = function ($index) {
    $scope.comment.splice($index, 1);
}
```

}

And the same JS function for the reply section:

```
function FrmController2($scope) {
$scope.comment = [];
$scope.btn_add = function () {
    if ($scope.txtcomment2 != '') {
        $scope.comment.push($scope.txtcomment2);
        $scope.txtcomment2 = "";
    }
}
$scope.remItem = function ($index) {
    $scope.comment.splice($index, 1);
}
```

}

Also can someone show me how to add an image avatar for each section(comment and reply),also date and time,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you'll want to use this:

```
<textarea ng-repeat="comnt in comment | orderBy: $index : true" style='width:510px'> Reply: {{ comnt }} </textarea>
```

That will reverse the order of the replies, so the latest ones should show up on top.

EDIT:  I think this is what you mean:

```
    <div id='dv2'>
        <form ng-controller="FrmController2">
            <form ng-controller="FrmController2">
                <ul>
                    <textarea ng-repeat="comnt in comment" style='width:510px'> Reply: {{ comnt }} </textarea>
                </ul>
                <textarea ng-model="txtcomment2" placeholder="Reply..." style='width:510px'></textarea>
                <button ng-click='btn_add();' id="replyBtn" style='margin-top:5px;'>Reply</button>
            </form>
        </form>
    </div>
```

EDIT2 to answer your subsequent question.  I *think* this will work:

JS:

```
$scope.btn_add = function () {
    if ($scope.txtcomment2 != '') {
        var dateTime = new Date();
        $scope.comment.push({comment : $scope.txtcomment2, date : dateTime);
        $scope.dt.push(dateTime);
        $scope.txtcomment2 = "";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea ng-repeat="comnt in comment" style='width:510px'> Reply: {{comnt.date}} {{ comnt.comment }} </textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Chris and thank you for the response!It is working,but again when you type something in the reply section and press the button to post that reply,the text appears underneath,and I'm trying to bring it above the reply section box,so when you press the button to post a reply,to appear above the reply text area,but below the comment one.

Comment: Wait.. so you want the replies above the box to reply?  If that's the case, just move the html for the replies above the reply box html.

Comment: Just added a picture demo to see what I have in mind and what I'm trying to do,it's on the very top of my post!

Comment: Right... just move the HTML element up higher.  I edited my answer to facilitate what I think you're asking for.

Comment: Yep,now it worked:)Was focused more on the JS side,and it was as easy as to look the html:)Still need to make that comment/reply section a bit better.Any suggestions on how to add an avatar image for both with date and time?Thank you!

Comment: Sure.  Be sure to mark my answer as the answer for your question though.  I'll add the logic in my answer.

Comment: The time code doesn't work with me for some reason!Any ideas on how to add an avatar as well?Thanks!